# livewire set value of hidden input on button click

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I want to do something seemingly simple in livewire. I want to set the value of a hidden input field based on an attribute from a button that's clicked. I can console.log the ID I'm looking for, and it works. I can see that the value of the input is updated in the UI, however, it's updated to what appears to be the Livewire hash or ID of the element. I just want the regular id. Am I doing this wrong?

here's the link that's clicked, and I want to put the `$status->id` into the hidden input:

```
<a role="button" id="task_status_{{ $status->id }}" class="add-task-btn"><i class="mdi mdi-plus-circle h5 text-muted" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#createOrUpdateTask"></i></a>
```

The input:

```
<input id="status_id_input" value="" hidden>
```

The js:

```
 $('.add-task-btn').on('click', function(el) {
                    let status = el.currentTarget.id.split('_')[2];
                    $("input[id=status_id_input]").val(status);
                });
```

Maybe I'm not thinking about this in a livewire-y way, but this is something I've done countless times in the past.

If I console.log the status I get a number, like 2, for example.

But when I look at the markup, the value of the input is like this:

`wTz06yjQoQErKT3p36EKP4zZwWjJgIsUOttX4URL`

I was wanting to do this without a round-trip to the server since it's just a simple thing.

Answer (score -1):

Change your code from this

```
<input id="status_id_input" value="" hidden>
```

To this

```
<input id="status_id_input" value="yourvalue" type="hidden">
```

Comment: that didn't work..